# Does my personal philosophy have a name?

Tags: existence, descartes

I am not trained in philosophical thinking nor have I read philosophy except for the motto "I think therefore I am".

---

My personal philosophy

1. I know that something exists (by observation and by observation of the observer).
2. I am mystified that anything can exist including myself.
3. I am a radical agnostic in that I know nothing except 1. above.
4. I act as though my world is real.
5. I see my existence as purposeless.
6. I am capable of enjoying my life without a purpose.
7. I don't know how to account for the sensation of physical pain in my philosophy. Everything else is just part of the game.

---

Is there a name in philosophy for this attitude to life? Has it been written about? Whom should I read?

*Note: I am not sure which tags I should use.*

Comment: Sounds like [Humean skepticism](https://iep.utm.edu/hume/).

Comment: I'm curious why physical pain, specifically, presents a difficulty in your philosophy?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like optimistic nihilism.

Point 2 shows similarities to solipsism though (argument that nothing exists except the arguer's mind), but you still give a probability for you yourself may not even exist.

Other points indicate you have views similar to existential nihilism (the view that life has no intrinsic value) and the fact that even though you believe life has no intrinsic value it doesn't keep you from living life normally or without having an existential crisis accounts for the "optimistic" part. You think that life has no value or meaning per se, but this does not keep you from enjoying your life as is.

Answer (score 1):

I am similar in the way that I am also not an official philosopher with credentials, but I am an amateur and a philosopher wanna-be. My ideas evolve on what I know to be true, the constant here and now, what I think and what I feel, what is and can be within reach of the current moment. Your ideas seem to be derived from your outlook on things. Making conclusions regarding your ideas of worth and predictability. This seems to be a case of lacking faith. I suffered from this for a very long time. I believe that we have to let go of the unknowns, trust and expect that all will pan out very similar to our recent past, except for the changes you aim to make. I would say the nature of your philosophy says you are seeking clarity, hope, and courage in finding your faith to live in peace and to be at ease at the moment knowing it will all amount to something meaningful, worthy and rewarding.